# QGIS creates gaps while generating tiles with Write vector tiles (XYZ)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, tiles, vector-tiles, gap

In QGIS 3.22.4 I am generating *vector* tiles from *multiline* layer using **Write Vector Tiles (XYZ)** function.

The problem is, that the algorithm generates gaps at intersection of features:
[image]

I am generating tiles with enough detailed zoom level. Below is example of tile with zoom level 15 displayed with coresponding scale 1:18056 and gap is visible.
[image]
Anyone has an idea where is the problem?

Comment: I reported it as a bug: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/49947